# OMNET++: How to obtain frame's source MAC Address in INET 4.0?

Tags: c++, omnet++, mac-address, inet, data-link-layer

I am using `INET` Framework 4.0 with `OMNET++`. I have customised my `Ieee80211ScalarRadio` module to read signal power and source MAC Address of the beacons received from various APs in my `AdhocHost`.
Here is my custom `CIeee80211ScalarRadio.ned` file:

```
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadio;

module CIeee80211ScalarRadio extends Ieee80211ScalarRadio
{
    @class(inet::physicallayer::CIeee80211ScalarRadio);
}
```

And here is the corresponding `CIeee80211ScalarRadio.cc` file:

```
#include "inet/physicallayer/ieee80211/packetlevel/Ieee80211Radio.h"
#include "inet/physicallayer/common/packetlevel/SignalTag_m.h"
#include "inet/linklayer/common/MacAddressTag_m.h"


#include <omnetpp.h>
#include <string>

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

namespace inet{
namespace physicallayer{
class CIeee80211ScalarRadio : public Ieee80211Radio{
protected:
   virtual void sendUp(Packet *macFrame) override;
};

Define_Module(CIeee80211ScalarRadio);

void CIeee80211ScalarRadio::sendUp(Packet *macFrame)
{
    if (macFrame->findTag<SignalPowerInd>() != nullptr) {
           auto signalPowerInd = macFrame->getTag<SignalPowerInd>();
           auto rxPower = signalPowerInd->getPower().get();
           double pdBm = 10*log10(rxPower)+30;
           EV_INFO << "RX power = " << pdBm << " dBm" << endl;
    }
    if(macFrame->findTag<MacAddress>() != nullptr){
        auto macAddress = macFrame->getTag<MacAddress>();
        EV_INFO << "Mac Address = " << macAddress << endl;
    }

    Radio::sendUp(macFrame);
}
}//namespace physicallayer
}//namespace inet
```

As you can see, I am overriding `Ieee80211ScalarRadio`'s `sendUp()` method to obtain the values I want from the `macFrame`.
I can extract the `RxPower` successfully, however, when I do the same thing for `MacAddress`, I get the following compiler error in `INET`'s own source code:

```
../inet4/src/inet/common/packet/tag/TagSet.h:123:36: error: static_cast from 'std::__1::__vector_base<omnetpp::cObject *, std::__1::allocator<omnetpp::cObject *> >::value_type' (aka 'omnetpp::cObject *') to 'inet::MacAddress *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed
```

How can I get the `MacAddress` value without any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper name of tag which contains MAC address is `MacAddressInd`, not `MacAddress`. It is declared in `MacAddressTag_m.h` which you have included.

**EDIT**
Additional remark: the `MacAddressInd` contains two addresses: source and destination. So you should precise which one you want to obtain, for example:

```
auto macAddress = macFrame->getTag<MacAddressInd>()->getSrcAddress();
```

Comment: Thanks, the error has gone now, however, this doesn't work either. The `if` condition is false. That is, the `MacAddressInd` tag cannot be found.

Comment: It is because the radio layer does not look for a MAC address in received frame. The **MAC layer** recognizes the addresses. Try to run any `IEEE 802.11` example form `INET` and look at packets that are interchanged between these layers using object inspector.